# Scraping a page in PHP

Tags: php, parsing, dom

I want to scrape some data with Php Simple Dom parser from soccerstats.com, but I cannot because always appear the cookie page before loading the normal page.
How to bypass the cookie page?
My code is this:

```
<?php
    include_once('../scrapper/scrapper.php');
    $url = 'https://www.soccerstats.com/matches.asp';
    $html = file_get_html($url);

    $stats = array();
    foreach($html->find('table') as $table) {
        $stats[] = $table->outertext;
    }
    $results = implode(",", $stats);    

    echo $results; 
?>
```

Comment: You should rename your scraper with only one _p_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very quick look at the page `https://www.soccerstats.com/matches.asp` showed that what the "cookie page" really does is that **it requires the user to click on a button, which - when clicked - just sets a cookie `cookiesok` to a value of `yes`**, as seen in source of that page:

```
<button class="button button3" onclick=" setCookielocal('cookiesok', 'yes', 365)"><font size='4'>I agree. Continue to website.</font></button>
```

So, what we need to do is to somehow **make PHP to fetch the page with this cookie set.**

Since you're using the https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/ library and its function `file_get_html()`, I looked into the source code of that function and found out that it really uses the [`file_get_contents()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) behind the scenes - and at the same time it allows us to pass our own "context", which we can create via the [`stream_context_create()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php).

In short, **`stream_context_create()` allows us to create a context with required *cookies* to be used in the `file_get_html()` function.**

**Final code:**

```
<?php

    include_once '../scrapper/scrapper.php';

    // Options for the context we're about to create.
    $options = [
        "http" => [
            "header" => "Cookie: cookiesok=yes\r\n",
        ],
    ];

    // Context we're going to pass to the file_get_html() function.
    $context = stream_context_create($options);

    $url = 'https://www.soccerstats.com/matches.asp';
    $html = file_get_html($url, false, $context);

    $stats = array();
    foreach($html->find('table') as $table) {
        $stats[] = $table->outertext;
    }
    $results = implode(",", $stats);

    echo $results;
```